# how to step over list comprehension in pycharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am new to Python and Pycharm,

I am trying to step over a line with list comprehension,

but instead of moving me to the next line, pycharm is incrementing the loop in 1 iteration.

any ideas how to move to the next line without pushing F8 3000 times?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

PyCharm has 'Run to Cursor' option - just move your cursor one line down and hit it.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint at the next line of code after the comprehension and then hit play again.